# How can i reuse a single method instead of creating multiple copies

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a method that opens a folder browser dialog then sets a string property to configuration application settings.

As I have multiple folders that can be configured on the same page. I would like to be able to reuse the same method. What should I be looking at to do this?

I have tried passing in a unique parameter but the method needs to call the FirstFolder, SecondFolder etc properties to get and set the value, how can change these target properties within one method at run time?

ConfigurationView.xaml

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="First Folder : "/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding FirstFolder}"/>
    <Button Content=". ." cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [OpenFolderDialog]"/>
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Text="Second Folder : " />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding SecondFolder}" />
    <Button Content=". ." cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [OpenFolderDialog]"/>
</StackPanel>
```

ConfigurationViewModel.cs

```
public class ConfigLocationsViewModel : Screen
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;

    private firstFolder, secondFolder;

    public string FirstFolder
    {
        get { return firstFolder; }
        set { firstFolder= value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FirstFolder); }
    }

    public string SecondFolder
    {
        get { return secondFolder; }
        set { secondFolder= value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SecondFolder); }
    }

    public ConfigLocationsViewModel(IConfiguration config, IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        _config = config;
        _dialogService = dialogService;

        FirstFolder = _config.GetValue<string>("FolderLocations:FirstFolder");
        SecondFolder= _config.GetValue<string>("FolderLocations:SecondFolder");
    }

    public void SaveFirstFolder() => SaveSettings.AddOrUpdateAppSetting("FolderLocations:FirstFolder", FirstFolder);
    public void SaveSecondFolder() => SaveSettings.AddOrUpdateAppSetting("FolderLocations:SecondFolder", SecondFolder);

    // How to reuse this for Multiple Folders not just "FirstFolder"
    public void OpenFirstFolderDialog()
    {
        var settings = new FolderBrowserDialogSettings
        {
            Description = "Select First folder.",
            SelectedPath = IOPath.GetDirectoryName(FirstFolder ?? Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
        };

        bool? success = _dialogService.ShowFolderBrowserDialog(this, settings);
        if (success == true)
        {
            FirstFolder = settings.SelectedPath + @"\";
            SaveFirstFolder();
        }
    }

    public void OpenSecondFolderDialog()
    {
        var settings = new FolderBrowserDialogSettings
        {
            Description = "Select Second folder.",
            SelectedPath = IOPath.GetDirectoryName(SecondFolder ?? Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
        };

        bool? success = _dialogService.ShowFolderBrowserDialog(this, settings);
        if (success == true)
        {
            SecondFolder = settings.SelectedPath + @"\";
            SaveSecondtFolder();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I couldn't figure out a "clever" way to do this so I used a simple switch statement  passing in a identifying parameter.

```
public void OpenFolderDialog(string folder)
{
    var settings = new FolderBrowserDialogSettings
    {
        Description = $"Select {folder} folder.",
        SelectedPath = IOPath.GetDirectoryName(folder ?? Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
    };

    bool? success = _dialogService.ShowFolderBrowserDialog(this, settings);
    if (success == true)
    {
        switch(binding)
        {
            case "FirstFolder":
                FirstFolder = settings.SelectedPath + @"\";
                SaveFirstFolder();
                break;
            case "SecondFolder":
                SecondFolder= settings.SelectedPath + @"\";
                SaveSecondFolder();
                break;
             etc..
             etc..
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the command binding:

```
<Button Command="{Binding OpenFolderCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding FirstFolder}"/>

<Button Command="{Binding OpenFolderCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SecondFolder}"/>
```